# Getting ClassNotFoundException from the same folder where class file is present

Tags: java, command-line, program-entry-point, classnotfoundexception

I have written a very simple java program and compiled using java 11.
Here is the code :

```
public class Simple
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    
    System.out.println(" here ") ;
    }

}
```

It compiles fine from Windows command line (javac Simple.java) but when I try to run using
java Simple (from same folder)
I see this error:-

```
C:\work_related>java Simple
Error: Could not find or load main class Simple
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Simple
```

I tried setting path to current folder as well by doing set path=%path%;. but doesn't make any difference.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a package involved you haven't shown us? If the answer is no, then try `java -cp . Simple` Incidentally, `%PATH%` is quite a different thing from classpath. You need to find out about their meanings

Comment: It would ordinarily work without the `-cp .` flag, unless the `CLASSPATH` environment variable has been set to something that doesn’t include `.`. Check whether your system has a setting for `CLASSPATH` instead of `PATH`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting classpath env variable did the trick as mentioned by g00se in comments.
As g00se has suggested it is better to refer to classpath from command line while running the application as:

java -cp . Simple

Comment: As it happens, I would *not* recommend set the classpath as an env var. It's not necessary and most likely you'll forget you've done it and wonder why there are errors, as you've *already proved* ;)